# C# Interactive in Visual Studio Community on Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to do some treehouse tutorials on C#. Unfortunately, the instructor is teaching this course in an windows machine with a windows version of VS Community while I follow along VS Community for mac. Got to a point where she is trying to use the C# interactive (REPL) but I can't seem to find it on the mac version. Anyone know if its even possible to do this on the mac? Thanks.

Comment: No, surprised you didn't see this: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/c-interactive-window-visual-studio-preview-mac

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks. No idea how I missed that. I looked in the teachers notes/questions for the video on that lesson and got nothing. Thanks much.

Comment: As of 2020 we have Xamarin Workbooks for the Mac - see my answer below for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511744/7107094

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Interactive Window support in VS **2017 Mac**.

Future versions may have this feature. If it is important you could use Parallels and run the Windows version.

Or work around it by doing the same sorts of things with a debugger and Immediate Window.

Answer (score 14):

You can't run it in Visual Studio. You can, however, use the terminal.

When you install `mono` the command `csharp` gets installed as well.
Simply type `csharp` and the terminal will become a C# interactive window.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get syntax highlighting for the REPL in the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Mono installed you can also use: `csi`

[image: example of csi prompt]

Comment: this is pretty awesome! any idea how to make it paste last typed command like in full VS? (alt+up key)

Comment: @zaitsman You can use `rlwrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xamarin Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/workbooks/workbook)!

If you don't like Xamarin Workbooks for whatever reason, you can also use `csi` in the console, but it doesn't have code completions :/ I couldn't edit Sachin's answer above, but to be more clear, all you need to do is open the terminal and type `csi` to start the C# interactive tool. Of course this only works after you've installed Visual Studio (it should have installed Mono in the process).